# Why wp_head() function not loading style.css?

Tags: theme-development, themes, wp-head

I am totally new to WordPress and developing my own theme but **function.php** is not loading CSS file.

header.php

```
<html>
    <head>     
        <?php wp_head(); ?>            
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>I'm header.php</h2>
```

single.php

```
<?php
get_header();
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php }

?>
```

function.php

```
<?php
function main_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'main_css' );
```

style.css

```
/* 
Theme Name: My Theme
Author: Tesla
Version: 1.0    
*/
body{
    color: green;
}
h1{
    color: pink;
}
```

I have tried many ways but it's not loading even disable the browser cookies, hard refresh, reinstall the Wordpress.

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: I have added <link rel='stylesheet' id='my-theme' href='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' /> and its workd fine but I think this is not a proper way to inlcude the CSS and JS files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme functions file name must be called `functions.php` not `function.php`. This can cause your code to not implement? You must check carefully.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Mr.Optical. It works. I have been searching the solution for 2 days.

Comment: @PollyTearesa you’re welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned by Mr. Optical and Mat, the name of your functions files needs to be functions.php.

I think it's great that you're looking to learn how to code a WordPress Theme. One thing I recommend for aspiring theme developers is downloading the [Underscores Starter Theme](http://underscores.me/) which is maintained by the team at Automattic.

This will give you the foundation that you can use for your theme or it can serve as a reference to learn from.

I also recommend book marking the [WordPress Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/). There, you'll get valuable information on how to properly develop a WordPress Theme.